# Why is v2 undefined but then has a value of the last element in an array?

Tags: javascript, variables, foreach, scope

I am using template literals. In the console I put this code:

```
var v2;
a=[1,2,3,0,2.5];
b=[
  `Math.round(${v2})`
];
var v;
a.forEach( v  => {
    console.log(v);
    v2=v;
    console.log(b[0]);                
  }
          
)
```

When I first execute the code in the console the interpolated value of v2 is 'undefined'. I then execute the code a second time and the value of the interpolated value is 2.5, the last value in the array of numbers. To solve this I have to move the declaration of the b array, which has the template literal, into the forEach function. Why is v2 undefined, then has a value?

Comment: When the string is created, `v2` is undefined.

Comment: Because when you first run the code, you set the value to the global variable (in the loop). Variables are not re-declared, hence the value stays in the already-declared variable when you run the same code again.

Comment: I think your question basically boils down to asking why something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/amsy9wcg/1) doesn't re-set `x` back to `undefined`, right?

Comment: I am not sure of the scope of the variable in the template literal.

Comment: It's global as you've written it in to the example, and run the code in the console. You can't expect `v2` to have a value before the loop will be executed.

Comment: @Nick Parsons was close. I think I worked it out. It is to do with the console. I assumed that when I ran the code that all the variables would start out as some value and not retain the value from the previous code execution. The v2 starts out undefined then is assigned a value later on. So, when I rerun the code in the console, it still has that value from the previous code run.I declared it as a var so I can rerun the code without the redeclaration error.If this was in a script then it would refresh everything so to speak.I would have to refresh the page manually to clear all the variables.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @adiga's comment: When `b` is assigned, an array is created with a string. That string receives its value, incorporating the value of `v2`, at the same time. `v2` has never been assigned to yet, so it is the default value `undefined`.

The string is interpolated when the JavaScript engine runs the statement the string is in; in your case, when the array is declared and the contents are put into it. It produces an immutable string and that's it - you can't have a string that changes over time or reevaluates its contents. The closest you can get is making a function that returns that string, because it creates a new string every time you call the function.

Comment: 'You can't have a string that reevaluates its contents'   - I am not sure what that means. v2 was reevaluated, wasn't it? It was undefined, then the last value of the array. Is v2 in the string?

Comment: After the line where `b` is initialized, it contains an array with a single string. This string's value is already set in stone. The string can't change. What you can do is swap it out from the array and put a *new* string into the array. But that string will remain the same, no matter what you do afterwards to whatever went into the string interpolation.